# What is the meaning of ～てきた in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

> A: その封筒を開けると、便箋一枚の手紙と一万円札２枚が出てきた。

My translation:

> A: If that envelop is opened, one sheet of letter paper and 2 sheets of 10 thousand yen bills 出てきた.

In my understanding, ～てきた represents

- action done in the past and it continues up to the present, "~started to, ~has begun to, etc". For example,

  - 雨が降ってきた。It started to rain.
  - 人口が増えてきた。The population has begun to grow.
- after doing the ～て action, the speaker return to the place where she/he says the sentence.

  - 親を連れてきた。I brought my parents here.
  - 弁当を買ってきた。 I bought a meal and came here with that meal.

But in the sentence A, I think the usage of ～出てきた does not make sense so ～出た should be used instead.

## Question

What is the meaning of ～てきた in the sentence A?

Comment: It means "came out".

Comment: @istrasci: OK. Do you know the reason that ～てきた should be used here rather than 出た?

Comment: @優しいエイリアン To indicate direction toward the subject. The money emerged from the envelope out toward the person who opened it.

Comment: The くる is [#9(補助動詞)-㋓ in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/64270/meaning/m0u/):「ある動作・状態をそのまま続けながら、こちらへ近づく。また、そのようにしてこちらへ至る。『敵が押し寄せてくる』『付き添ってくる』」.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by itrasci、出てきた would mean "came out", from an already understood location and towards the subject.

> その封筒を開けると、便箋一枚の手紙と一万円札２枚が出てきた。

- "When (he) opened the envelope, there was a letter written on a single sheet of stationary and two ten-thousand yen bills."

If you use 出た instead... I think it might sound like the things just kind of "appeared", and not necessarily from the envelope.

> その封筒を開けると、便箋一枚の手紙と一万円札２枚が出た。

- "When (he) opened the envelope, a letter written on a single sheet of stationary and two ten-thousand yen bills appeared."

Begging the question, where from?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case it means came out of the envelope.

出る　＋　来る

出て来る